# Trying to query Bitbucket API with Python script, getting an error

Tags: python, api, bitbucket

I am trying to write a python script that sends an API query to the Bitbucket Server API to create a new file in my repository. I'm sending the query outlined in [this documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v809/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-browse-path-put) and authenticating with my Bitbucket account's HTTP access token and I've been able to successfully do this in Postman. However, when I run my python script sending the same query, I get a 500 response with the message "An error occurred while processing the request. Check the server logs for more information".

Here is the script that I've written:

```
import json
import requests

def handler(context, inputs):
    jsonOut = json.dumps(inputs, separators=(',', ':'))
    print("Inputs were {0}".format(jsonOut))

    # Set the API endpoint URL
    project = '{project name}'
    repo = '{repo name}'
    fileName = 'test789.txt'
    url = f'https://{{My Bitbucket server url}}/rest/api/latest/projects/{project}/repos/{repo}/browse/{fileName}' 
    print('url: ' + url)

    token = "{my HTTP access token}"

    # Set the headers with the encoded key
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    # Set the body for the API call
    branchName = 'branch-name'
    content = inputs['contents']
    commitMsg = 'Test creating a file with a python script'
    files = {
        'branch': branchName,
        'content': content,
        'message': commitMsg,
        'sourceBranch': 'master'
    }

    # Make the API call to create the new branch
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)

    # Check if the request was successful
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Status code: " + str(response.status_code) + "\n" + response.json()["errors"][0]["message"])

    print("YML file pushed to BitBucket successfully.")

inputs = {"contents": "Flippity Floo"}
handler("context", inputs)
```

Is there anyone who is familiar with the Bitbucket server API who can see what I'm doing wrong? I suspect my authentication method is the cause, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I'd  remove explicit `Content-Type` header. `requests` shall deal with it on its own

Comment: That did the trick. After removing the Content-Type header, the request went through successfully. Thanks!